# setEraseCredentialsAfterAuthentication(false) isn't working as I expect it

Tags: spring, spring-security

In my SecurityConfig class (with annotations `@Configuration @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true`) I have a Bean that looks like this:

```
@Bean
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
        log.debug("ANDY: In authenticationManager....");
        ProviderManager providerManager = new ProviderManager(authenticationProvider);
        if (providerManager.isEraseCredentialsAfterAuthentication()) {
            log.debug("ANDY: Provider set to erase creds, changing to NOT do this");
            providerManager.setEraseCredentialsAfterAuthentication(false);
        }
        return providerManager;
        // return new ProviderManager(authenticationProvider);
    }
```

The `authenticationProvider` is a custom provider that implements `AuthenticationProvider`.

I can see from debug messages that it get's picked up, however when I try to user the credentials in my `RequestInterceptor` (I use feign) like this:

```
password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
```

It blows up because the Credentials are null. If I hardcode the password it works like a charm.

Any idea why this isn't working as I am expecting e.g. I should be able to get the password? And yes I'm new to Spring Security :-)

Answer (score 1):

I thinks this solves the problem:

```java
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        log.debug("ANDY: In configureGlobal");
        auth.eraseCredentials(false).authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
    }
```